# JavaScript: How to display value after each prompt

Tags: javascript

In my JavaScript program I have created prompt dialogue box in do-while loop. Prompt should run until user enter stop in prompt. When user enter value in prompt it should display on screen and another prompt should be generated. But in my case when I enter value for the first time in prompt another prompt get generated without displaying value. Can anyone tell me what's wrong in my code?

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>lab12</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#efe862">
    <h3 id="txt1"></h3>
</body>
<script> 
    myFunction();
    function myFunction() {
        do {
            var prom = window.prompt("Enter a text(stop to exit)");
        } while(prom != "stop");    
        document.getElementById("txt1").innerHTML = "The text is: " + prom;
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I added inside do but still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. The code to display it is outside the loop
2. Even if it was inside the loop, you're not giving the browser the opportunity to render it.

Try this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var prom = window.prompt("Enter a text (cancel to exit)");
  if (prom != null) {
      document.getElementById("txt1").innerHTML = "The text is: " + prom;
      setTimeout(myFunction, 0);
  }
}
myFunction();
```

```html
<h3 id="txt1"></h3>
```

The `setTimeout` function will yield control to the browser so it can render the text, before calling `myFunction` again.

Comment: Thank you so much but when I enter stop it shouldn't display prompt anymore...it should print for the last time and exit.

Comment: Yes, I found that highly annoying and opted for just clicking cancel instead. I'm sure you can figure out how to get it to stop on "stop" instead though, if that's what you really want.

Comment: I am sorry you find it annoying. I used do/while and used setTimeout but still it doesn't work. Would you please mind to edit code ?

Comment: The purpose of this site is not to serve ready-made snippets of code on a silver platter, but to answer specific programming-related questions. Your question has been answered, the rest I'm afraid you'll have to figure out on your own.

Comment: The dom is synchronous and will render even during a loop, the issue is that it will not be shown due to the prompt hides it.

Comment: @user7951676 In what way does the prompt "hide" it? And why does it not get hidden using the code in this answer, which also displays a prompt?

Answer (score -1):

This should work, instead of displaying the answer in the dom which is hidden due to the prompt, this puts the text in the next prompt.

```
<script>
function myFunction(){
var prom=prompt("Enter some text");
while(prom!="stop"){
prom=prompt("The text is "+prom);
}
}
myFunction();
</script>
```

Comment: Can you make it run ?

Comment: I just tested it and it does for me, what's not working?